# Print distinct numbers in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code to print the (distinct numbers), but I'm trying to check the inputs before the process, should be ten digits numbers only with only one space.
I tried while and try but still can't figure out:

```
def main():
    list1 = input("Enter ten numbers: ").split()
    set1 = set(list1)
    print(set1)
    list2 = list(set1)
    string = string.join(list2)
    print("The distinct numbers are: " + str(string))

main()
```

Comment: What do you mean "Check the inputs before the process"?

Comment: "ten digits numbers only with only one space": `split` will remove the spaces wherever they are. Then check the length and if they are numbers.

Comment: @chrisz I mean try and catch if the user input wrong value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler version using the `isnumeric()` method built in strings. Also, I put a loop around the `input` so as the user can easily retry in case of wrong data:

```
def main():
    while(True):
        numbers = input("Enter ten space-separated numbers: ").split()
        if len(numbers) != 10 or not all(n.isnumeric() for n in numbers):
            print("Wrong input, please retry")
            continue
        numbers = ' '.join(set(numbers))
        print("The distinct numbers are:", numbers)
        break # or return numbers if you need the data

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean check if there are ten numbers inputted?

```
import re

def check_input(input_string):
     compare_to = '\s'.join(10*['\d+'])
     if re.match(compare_to[:-1], input_string):
           return True
     return False
```

This is a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), it checks if the input string is equal to a specified input format. This one specifically checks whether 10 sets of at least 1 number `[\d+]` are added with a space inbetween `\s`.